# Pandas not updating all rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure it out.

What I'm trying to do is for every customer I want to check if they have some rows in the dataframe which meet some criteria. If that's true, then I want to update the rows for that customer, regardless if they are responsive to the original check with a 1 or 0. However, when I run the code below it only updates the rows where they were responsive to the original query:

```
temp = dfCustomers.loc[customer & activeCustomer & end_date_filter ]
```

What I'm assuming is happening is that `dfCustomers` is being narrowed down to the responsive rows, but I can't figure out. How to stop that from happening?

Bonus question, is there a better way to do this rather than looping?

```
dfCustomers = dfMerged.copy()

for cust in dfCustomers['Account Name'].unique():

    customer = dfCustomers['Account Name'] == cust
    activeCustomer = dfEngineCustomers['engine-customer'] == 1
    end_date_filter = dfEngineCustomers['correct-end-date'] >= pd.to_datetime('today')
    
    temp = dfCustomers.loc[customer & activeCustomer & end_date_filter ]
    
    if len(temp) > 0:
        dfCustomers.loc[(dfCustomers['Account Name'] == cust),'active-customer'] = 1
    else:
        dfCustomers.loc[(dfCustomers['Account Name'] == cust) & (dfCustomers['customer'] == 1) ,'active-customer'] = 0
```

Comment: Your code looks right. Could you provide a sample of your input data as well as your output data (pointing out what exactly you think it's wrong)?

Comment: I will have to see if I can sanitize it as it has a lot of confidential information :/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding you for loop, you might wanna look at [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
for customer, df_customer in dfCustomers.groupby('Account Name'):
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured this out, I don't actually know why this works but the line:

```
dfCustomers.loc[(dfCustomers['Account Name'] == cust),'active-customer'] = 1
```

should be:

```
dfCustomers.loc[dfCustomers['Account Name'] == cust,'active-customer'] = 1
```

No brackets.

Anybody know why this makes a difference, I'm coming from Java/PHP?